# Using an OAuth2 Bearer Token at later point in time

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, bearer-token

**Situation**
We are implementing a service, which is responsible to delay the invocation of actions. The user calls our service to invoke an action, which will be executed at a later point in time (schedule).
Our service needs to call another service to invoke the action at the correct point in time using a bearer token from the customer to authenticate.

**Problem**
The bearer token we get from the customer is only valid for 30 minutes. How can we solve the problem, that if the scheduled action is more than 30 minutes in the future, our service will not be authorized to invoke the action?

Answer (score 1):

access tokens are normally short lived you may be able to request a refresh token they are longer lived and can be used to request a new access token when it has expired this depends upon your system.